# Dimension of the set of mxn complex component matrices over real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

What is the dimension of $M_m$$_x$$_n$$\mathbb{C}$ when considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

My approach: If I take an mxn matrix of complex entries and I want to write this as a linear combination of reals, I think that the dimension would have to be $2mn$ since the matrix could be broken down into two matrices, one containing the real entries and another containing the complex entries. E.g. if $a+bi$ is a component of the original mxn matrix, the $a$ part would be in one of the broken down matrices and the $bi$ part would be in the other. Then each of these two matrices can be broken down using $mn$ $mxn$ matrices which is how I get this conclusion. Is there anything I am doing wrong here I am very unsure for some reason?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: You can write down a basis using your correct intuition.

Comment: Just one point: split complex matrices into matrices containing real respectively _imaginary_ entries.

Comment: More generally, you can ask for the dimension of $V^{m\times n}$ if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reasoning is correct. It would be 2*m*n (m*n for the real part for each position and m*n for the imaginary part for each position).